# Error in creating 2 tables in Green Screen STRSQL

Tags: sql

I'm getting an error while trying to create 2 tables in Green Screen STRSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/CUSTOMER AS (SELECT * FROM CBHHUBFP/SSCUSTP)

CREATE TABLE QTEMP/ADDRESS AS (SELECT * FROM QTEMP/CUSTOMER)
```

**ERROR: Keyword Create not expected 
Valied Tokens End-Of-Statement**

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using STRSQL you can only execute one SQL statement at time.

Comment: Effectively true, but multiple statements can be combined, to run as just **one** Dynamic Compound *statement*. Though given the sqlcode=-104 msg SQL0104 indicates an expectation of something other than DATA or WITH has me wondering what ancient version [as predecessor] of DB2 for i or if the OP does not reflect exactly of either what was requested or what was the output.

Answer (score 0):

Re my comment to the accepted answer by @dcieslak, the following is an example of a Dynamic Compound Statement (DCS) with syntax that should be valid for use with the /*SYS naming-option, on any system [level of DB2 for IBM i], since the availability of that DCS feature; notice the addition of the WITH DATA clause to make the statement syntactically correct, and enclosing the two semicolon separated requests as `CREATE TABLE` statements, inside of the `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
begin                                                          
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/CUSTOMER AS (SELECT * FROM qiws/qcustcdt   )
 with data                                                     
;                                                              
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/ADDRESS AS (SELECT * FROM QTEMP/CUSTOMER)   
 with data                                                     
;                                                              
end
-- Table ADDRESS created in QTEMP. /* <-- feedback of final rqs */
```

While that is possible to enter as a single request, there is likely no point in coding that, per the extra overhead; perhaps if run under isolation and doing more work and coding exception handling, then there would be value. IOW, the Start Interactive SQL Session (STRSQL) scripting environment allows the isolation and user decisions to react to exceptions when the statement are entered individually, successively, Enter pressed after each.

So unless the idea is to test what might be written in a routine [as a compound statement, statements between BEGIN-END pairs] without actually coding the `CREATE PROCEDURE` [or `CREATE FUNCTION` ¿or `CREATE TRIGGER`?] with a *routine-body*, then the implicitly created routine [as procedure] that is then run and deleted to implement the DCS, is probably mostly just a bunch of extra/unnecessary work.